# KONG's control plane & data plane mapping

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-ingress

I am new to KONG and currently installed KONG in hybrid mode (CP/DP separated).

Just want to check if we have multiple DPs for one CP and want to deploy the service.
In that case do we need to mention anywhere about the DPs details like on service level configuration or CPs level.

My understanding so far:
DP nodes will share the configuration. It caches the contents of your database in memory. The cached entities include Services, Routes, Consumers, Plugins, Credentials, etc… Since those values are in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CP is listening for DPs. You don't declare anywhere DP, just you give to the DP the details to connect to the CP.

You say:

> DP nodes will share the configuration. It caches the contents of your database in memory. The cached entities include Services, Routes, Consumers, Plugins, Credentials, etc… Since those values are in memory.

The DP doesn't have access to the database, this is the role of the control plan cf the [documentation](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/2.7.x/plan-and-deploy/hybrid-mode/), the schema is very clear:

> control plane (CP), where configuration is managed and the Admin API is served from; and data plane (DP), which serves traffic for the proxy.

> Once connected, every Admin API or Kong Manager action on the control plane triggers an update to the data planes in the cluster.